# Default terms based on user role

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, users, taxonomy-terms

I have Node with taxonomy terms.
Example

- Term A
- Term B
- Term C

and user role like this

- Role 1
- Role 2
- Role 3

Using [Taxonomy Access Control(TAC)](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) I can limit Role 1 can add all terms, Role 2 only add Term B, Role 3 only add term C.

With CSS I can hide disabled options, so when Role 3 want to add content. ex: Role 3 will only see Term C.

But how can I make Term C autofilled when Role 3 want to add. Right now Role 3 must choose or fill two options, nothing and Term C.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be better ways to do it, but this what I did in my case.

1. In hook_form_alter loop through the '#options' for this field.
2. Store every item in a new array skipping the one you don't want as options for this field.
    (in my case it was the item at index 0 with value 'N/A').
3. Assign this new array of options as '#options' for the field.

Worked for me.

Comment: Thans @amir0220